# Styled buttons won't let me change android:margin_layout

Tags: android, styles, android-button

Here's my button style:

```
<style name="StandardButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_mib_standard</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_text</item>
    <item name="android:padding">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
</style>
```

Why won't eclipse list `android:margin_layout` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `android:layout_margin`, and even if the `ADT Plugin` does not autocomplete this for you, it is probably just a bug in the `ADT Plugin` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

it isn't listed cause it is an attribute of the layoutParams that depends on the parent view type.
So it isn't listed cause it's possible that "android:layout_margin" isn't defined for the layout in which the view is placed.

By the way i think that if you define it in the style will work with no problem as soon as the parent use the parameter ( linearLayout, relativeLayout ecc. ).

PS. sry for my english ^^